# getting started with firebase with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just getting started with firebase and javascript html to make a website for my app.

all I'm trying to do is access any value from firebase and print it on the website.

I followed firebase's quickstart tutorial and copied the exact same code they have: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1D0_wFlXgo

here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>

    </head>


<body>

    <h1 id="bigOne"></h1>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyD0C9hhfpdKEIahisG0VNInZZGjCyf5Lo0",
        authDomain: "game-of-chats-ce897.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://game-of-chats-ce897.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "game-of-chats-ce897.appspot.com",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        var bigOne = document.getElementById('bigOne');
        var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');

        dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText) = snap.val())

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

am I missing something? I am new so there might be one small step that I'm missing.

Comment: You have an extra `)` at the end of this line `dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText) = snap.val())`.

Comment: But as a side note, I also suggest that you check your Rules under `Databases` in `console.firebase.google.com` to make sure that you actually have `read`/`write` permissions! For development, you can change `false` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with:**

```
dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    bigOne.innerText = snapshot.val();
});
```